Tkinter: how to calculate the size of a widget
At the moment I'm planning to write a Minesweeper game in Python using Tkinter.
I'm trying to find an elegant way to determine the height of the playfield buttons based on the font used on these buttons. Then I can set the colum widths of the grid to that value to get square buttons.
This is an abridged version of the code I've got so far:
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame
from tkinter.font import nametofont

CELL_SIZE = 21

class MainGui(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def init(self):
        self.button = Button(self)
        self.button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="ensw")

        self.columnconfigure(0, minsize=CELL_SIZE)
        self.rowconfigure(0, minsize=CELL_SIZE)

        self.pack()

        font = nametofont(self.button.cget("font"))
        print(font)
        print(font.metrics())
        pady2 = self.button.cget("pady")
        print(pady2)
        bd = self.button.cget("bd")
        print(bd)

def main():
    main_window = Tk()
    main_gui = MainGui()
    main_gui.init()
    main_window.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

When I look at the test output, I see that the button uses TkDefaultFont, which has a linespace of 15 pixels.
Border width (bd) of the button = 2 and pady = 1. I would expect the minimal button height to be 15 + 2×bd + 2×pady = 15 + 2×2 + 2×1 = 21 pixels.
However, trying out different values for CELL_SIZE, I found out that the button height will never go below 26 pixels. Why 26?
I tried setting the button's bd and pady to zero. Then I get a height of 20 pixels. That would make sense given the above, since it's exactly 6 pixels less then 26. It still leaves 5 pixels unaccounted for, though.
PS: I read in another SO post that it might be a better idea to use Label's instead of Button's.
When using a label I do get the minimal height of 21 pixels I'd expect.
However, I'm still curious why buttons have this minimal height of 26 pixels.

One difference between a Button and a Label is that the Button's text shifts slightly when it is depressed.  Perhaps the extra space is to allow room for that shift to occur.

You also need to consider the highlight thickness value.

Out of curiosity, why do you need to know the size? And if you need the size, do you need the size before the screen is visible, or can you wait until after it has been rendered for the first time? For example, you could let Tkinter layout the window, and then set the minsize after the window first appears.

@BryanOakley My idea is to set the font I like for the buttons, then determine the height of the buttons when they're using that font. Then I want to set the button width to that same value, so I get square buttons.
Not sure if I need/have to wait for the widgets to render.  I tried using winfo() on the buttons after they had been rendered, but that didn't seem to give me the info I needed.

If you just want a square button, then you don't need to care why the calculated height is not the same as the final height.  Just set both the width and height of the button to the same in pixels.

@acw1668 I want to be able to set a certain font fot the buttons and then determine the actual size of the buttons. Of course I can choose 'a' value and set both column width and row height to that value, but that would involve a hard-coded value, which is not what I'm going for.

You already get the final height (26 as you said but you don't post how you get this value) of the button, then you can set the width of the button to the same as the height.  Note that 26 is in pixels, so you need to find a way to set the width of the button in pixels.  One of the way is to assign image option of the button to an image of size 1x1.

@acw1668 26 is a hard-coded value. I tried different sizes and found out that the button's height wouldn't go below 26. I'll change my first post to make it clearer.
I use grid's minsize to set row height and column width.
